# get_the_title in edit post_link

Tags: functions

Basically I would like to link to the edit post interface in Wordpress with the string to display being the post title. Cannot get it to work have tried any syntax that I could come up with, but I am also only 2 days into php.

Here is what I came up with. It creates a link but does not display the post title.

```
<a href=<?php edit_post_link('<?php echo get_the_title($ID);?>'); ?> </a>
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/edit_post_link http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_title

Answer (score 0):

[`edit_post_link`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/edit_post_link) should not be used as href attribute. Try the following:

```
<?php edit_post_link( get_the_title( get_the_ID() ) ); ?>
```